# nextjs+Dockerfile: env variables pass to nextjs.config.js

Tags: next.js, dockerfile

I have a `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  .........
  env: {
    BASE_URL: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000',
  },
  ............
};
```

Now I want to change the `BASE_URL` while building docker image

my `Dockerfile` file

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN yarn install

ENV BASE_URL=http://yy.yyy.yy.yy:80

# Copy all files
COPY ./ ./

RUN yarn build
```

So passing `ENV BASE_URL=http://yy.yyy.yy.yy:80` in Dockerfile will it help to change the `BASE_URL: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000'` in the `next.config.js`

Or what the way i can change the `BASE_URL`

Comment: I'd recommend you use a `.env` file to setup your environment variables instead. See [Next.js Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENV BASE_URL=http://yy.yyy.yy.yy:80` in your docker file will set an environment variable `BASE_URL` to it's value, you need to read it for that variable.

```js
//next.config.js
module.exports = {
  .........
  env: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000', //read the value from env id empty use default value.
  },
  ............
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Created an entrypoint.sh file and put the below script in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# no verbose

set +x
# config
envFilename='.env'

nextFolder='./.next/'
function apply_path {
  # read all config file  
  while read line; do
    # no comment or not empty
    if [ "${line:0:1}" == "#" ] || [ "${line}" == "" ]; then
      continue
    fi

echo "***** line ******"
echo $line

# split
configName="$(cut -d'=' -f1 <<<"$line")"
configValue="$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<<"$line")"

echo "**** configName ****"
echo $configName

echo "**** configValue ****"
echo $configValue

# get system env
envValue=$(env | grep "^$configName=" | grep -oe '[^=]*$');

echo "**** envValue ****"
echo $envValue


# if config found
    if [ -n "$configValue" ] && [ -n "$envValue" ]; then
      # replace all
      echo "Replace: ${configValue} with: ${envValue}"
      find $nextFolder \( -type d -name .git -prune \) -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s#$configValue#$envValue#g"
    fi
    done < $envFilename
}
apply_path
echo "Starting Nextjs *** "
echo $API_URL
exec "$@"
```

Below is my Dockerfile referencing the entrypoint.sh file

```
# Dockerfile

# base image
FROM node:alpine

# create & set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

# install dependencies
COPY package*.json /usr/src/
RUN npm install

# copy source files
COPY . /usr/src

# start app
RUN npm run build

# Make it executable
RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000

# Execute script
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD npm run start
```

Modified by next.config.js to define an environment variable as per the below:

```
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
      // Will be available on both server and client
      API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
```

Comment: And run docker image with other environment for example in file '.env.stagging' like:
`docker run --env-file .env.stagging -p 3000:3000 [image]:[tag]`